# Orbeon add unique constraint to repeat grid

Tags: validation, xpath, orbeon, repeat

Given I have an Orbeon Form with a repeating grid/element named **promo-slots** with single control **slot**, is there a way to add a constraint so that each **slot** has a unique value?

I have tried following constraint, but it is not valid.

```
count(/form/promo-slots/slot[text() = .]) = 1
```

Here is the XForm instance definition

```
<xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
<form>
    <id/>
    <title/>                       
    <promo-slots>
        <slot/>
        <slot/>
        <slot/>
        <slot/>
    </promo-slots>
</form>
</xf:instance>
```

Comment: show the xml content also.. please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the value against "slot" values, but except the current control:

not (. = (../../promo-slots/slot except .))

Regards

Jez

Comment: '../../promo-slots/slot' is an xpath to return all of the slot elements (.. meams go up one level; you could equally well use a fully justified path ie /form/promo-slots/slot, but ../../{repeat-name}/{element-name} works where-ever you have your repeat). 'except .' removes the current element from the list, otherwise you would always compare the element with itself.